# Reported 'Receive' vs Download

Tags: download, resources

My computer is reporting that I am receiving (va wifi in case that matters at 30 Mbps; the active download is downloading at around 3.4 MB/S. (Perhaps this is a difference in the MB/S vs Mbps so I'm being as detailed as possible).

Is this discrepancy expected or should I be concerned?

Screen shot:

[image: Steam and Windows 8.1 Dialog]

Just in case I could see something, I checked Resource Monitor which actively shows and seems consistent with the 30 Mbps:

[image: Resource Monitor]

Any insight will be helpful. I know I could be missing something simple here.

**Update**: Download finished and everything went to zero... So there seems to be some connection

Comment: 8*3.4 is about 30 (27.2) you do know the difference between bytes and bits right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a difference between Mbps and MB/s. The first is millions of bits per second and the second is megabytes per second. There are not quite inter-convertible since there is overhead included in the MB/s calculation and the Mbps is raw transfer speed (it doesn't care what is transmitted, data or overhead). So if you divide Mbps by 10, you get (roughly) the speed in MB/s.

Comment: I am not sure I agree that they are not interconvertible.

Comment: @Ramhound Each byte has a start and stop bit added as it is transmitted on the line; therefore you need to divide the Mbps by at least 10 (more likely 10.24) to get the mygabytes per second. I'm not certain if the overhead is included.

Comment: Still don't agree with your math

Comment: I *think* you guys might be digging too much in to this. I think @LDC3 actually does have the answer in what I was missing. The details of the math, for my purposes, are not relevant...